# Does indicators calculates for each new bar? [backtrader]

Tags: python, finance, trading

I'm learning Python in finance with [backtrader](https://www.backtrader.com/).
Now, I've implemented a simple stragedy for buy/sell assests, but I have no a good understanding of the platform. The documentation is good but still is not clear for me.
So, for now there are 2 main questions:

1. Does indicators calculate the result each time when next method is
   running?  For example, in the `__init__` method I'm calculating SMA
   as follows: `self.sma =
   bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.datas[0],
   period=self.params.maperiod)`   As I can see from the log output the
   SMA is different each time `next` is calling.
2. If the inidcators re-calculates each time `next` is called may I declare a variable in the `__init__` to store the date of the last
   purchase date?

I've already implemented this and seems like all is working, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [was given](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/645/does-indicators-calculates-for-each-new-bar) by backtrader admin community:

> Indicators offer you always the latest value, automatically
>   recalculated. It's exactly the point, no interaction from the end user
>   for things which can be automatically done. You may declare anything
>   inside **init** and store anything in your declared variables. It's
>   your code and your way of doing it.